# Усилительная частица или союз "НЕ ТО ЧТО"

Tags: семантика, союзы, частица

Не могу понять какую функцию выполняет слово "НЕ ТО ЧТО" в следующих предложениях:

1. Я не даже не перекусил, не то что нормально пообедать.
2. Не то что хлеба, снега зимой не выпросишь.

Предполагаю, что это усилительная частица. Может я не прав.

Comment: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_491